# Вопросики по основам веба

Tags: веб-программирование

Друзья, ничего не понимаю в веб программировании. Но понадобилось для личных целей написать интернет магазин. Я сверстал все что нужно и задаюсь вопросом, а что дальше делать, ибо знания заканчиваются, а на просторах интернета очень очень много информации и выделить понятную конкретику не получается. Насколько я выделил, след. шаг - создать таблицу с товаром на phpmyadmin, вставить нужные запросы в html код вместо всяких Item_name на шаблоне. Дальше иду на любой сайт, покупаю домен и хостинг, заливаю папку с сайтом туда и вуаля все готово. Правильны ли мои действия, ничего не пропустил? Просто пишут что php *** и не надо. Есть серверная часть, но я так понял что ее роль будет выполнять хостинг и phpmyadmin. Объясните ошибки в понимании человеческим языком, а не языком статей, буду благодарен. Напомню, что в вебе я полный 0.

Comment: Хостинг - просто хранилище для файлов, заодно позволяющее выполнять некий серверный код (тот же php). phpmyadmin - это web-интерфейс для работы с БД MySQL, просто красивая обертка. Сколько бы вы через него таблиц ни создали, со страницами сайта это их никак не свяжет. должен быть код, на каком либо языке программирования, который будет осуществлять связь содержимого БД и отображаемого на сайте, т.е. код, который на основе содержимого БД создаст html разметку с этой информецией на лету. Это обычно и делают на php (и еще десятке других языков)

Comment: И если вы не используете никакие CMS (в принципе даже если используете), вы должны хорошо знать хотя бы один язык программирования. Хотя чаще всего требуется знать как минимум 2 языка: какой нибудь серверный (php, python, ruby, perl, java, JavaScript и т.п.) и клиентский - JavaScript, это по мимо знаний html и css. И еще надо знать SQL, для работы с БД. Так что быстро сделать не выйдет, придеться делать паралельно изучая целый набор технологий и языков

Answer (score 3):

> вставить нужные запросы в html код вместо всяких Item_name на шаблоне

это как раз и должен делать server-side. Если не нравится PHP - это может делать хоть Java, хоть C/C++, хоть ASM, лишь бы сервер выполнил программу, передав ей параметры и получил в ответ HTML.

В итоге все таки надо будет написать программу, которая обратиться к базе, получит из нее данные, далее пойдет посмотрит шаблон и расставит на нем данные из базы.

Но дальше будут еще приключения с хранением заказов, корзиной и наконец с персональными данными клиентов, которые не плохо бы не сделать достоянием общественности. Равно как и не дать хакерам возможности вмешаться в работу интернет-магазина для достижения своих корыстных целей.